# List of shortcuts used by macOS

Tags: macos, shortcut

Can I get a list of shortcuts that are used by macOS itself?

After an update I can't get `ctrl-alt-arrows` to be caught anymore by a tool I use but I can't figure out where they are going.

Comment: Do you mean this from Apple:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236 or are you looking for a tool to see what they are currently bound to and by what app?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can see them all

they are found here

[image: shortcuts]

Here you can find also the custom made one

If you know what was it doing you can find it faster in the category